# Midnight commander force xterm permanently

Tags: mc

I use Midnight Commander 4.8.16. 
If I set xterm 256 colors: `export TERM=screen-256color` then my mouse does not work, but forcing xterm: `mc -x` resolves the issue.

How to permanently force xterm (in mc config w/o using alias)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `TERM=screen-256color` seems to be the problem.  In the source code ([**`tty_check_term`**](https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/blob/master/lib/tty/tty.c#L77)), Midnight Commander treats that as "xterm" (and decides it supports a mouse) only if `DISPLAY` also is set.  Ignore the comment (it is wrong), and just read the source code.  The function return value is used in one place, from [**`main.c`**](https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/blob/master/src/main.c#L313) (again, ignore the comment...).

Midnight Commander ignores the actual contents of the terminal description, which happens to say that this configuration supports xterm-style mouse (i.e., the existence of `kmous=\E[M,` in the description).  It does this to work around its problems using slang, which also ignores the terminal description, looking only at `TERM`.  This is an old bug, dating back to the 1990s.

As a workaround, you *could* set `DISPLAY` to a dummy value if it is unset, since Midnight Commander does nothing more with it than this check.  Depending on your environment, that may have other side effects.

Further reading:

- [Extensions](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h2-EXTENSIONS) (terminfo - terminal capability data base)

> Be careful assigning the **`kmous`**  capability.   The  ncurses
>   wants  to  interpret it as **`KEY_MOUSE`**, for use by terminals
>   and emulators like xterm that  can  return  mouse-tracking
>   information in the keyboard-input stream.

Comment: Great, thanks for your elaborative answer! Setting `export DISPLAY=_` works like a charm. And should I tell you what am I using? - `mintty` in Windows 10 Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 currently), and everything seem to work fine :)